# Hibernate - How do I force an Outer Join in a "not in" @Filter?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, hibernate, filter

Ran into this issue today and I was not able to find any solution anywhere else. Actual entities in my application are much bigger, so here is a simplified version of the problem I am facing. I have an entity which has multiple child entities:

```
public class ParentEntity {
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Filter(name = "childEntity_1_filter", condition="state = 'ACTIVE'")
    private Set<ChildEntity_1> childEntity_1;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "parentEntity", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @Filter(name = "childEntity_2_filter", condition = "entity_name not in ('x', 'y')")
    private Set<ChildEntity_2> childEntity_2;
}
```

Now I am fetching the parent entity from the database using `Hibernate Criteria`.

So I specify both the joins and the filters from above, and then I specify the FetchMode for all these associations as `FetchMode.JOIN`.

This is where things don't work as expected. My records were not being returned properly and I debugged the SQL generated by hibernate. I saw something like:

```
# Note that this is hibernate generated sql
select
    ........
from
    parent_entity pe,
    childentity_1 ce1,
    childentity_2 ce2
where
    pe.id=ce1.id(+) and
    ce1.state (+)= 'ACTIVE' and        -- Notice the (+) here
    pe.id=ce2.id(+) and
    ce2.entity_name not in ('x', 'y'); -- Notice that (+) is missing here
```

As you can see above, the filter on the first child entity has the outer join properly applied to the query, while the "not in" filters do not have this join applied to them.

This is causing my query to not return records in some cases. Eg: If there are entities corresponding to the parent entity in the childentity_2 table, but those entities have entity_name = 'x'. This means that even though there are records after the join (since it is an outer join), all of them will be filtered out with the `not in` filter.

I tried changing the filter to use not equals condition:

```
@Filter(name = "childEntity_2_filter", condition = "entity_name != 'x' and ...")
```

In this case hibernate tried to add the `(+)`, but failed spectacularly. It added the `(+)` between the `!` and `=`. I tried various other combinations of the query like `<>`, but could not get anything to do what I wanted.

**Just to be clear, I know how to fix the query. My question is how to tell hibernate to fix the query.**

How do I fix the above @Filter annotation? My problem is that I have a lot of child entities which all have the `equals @Filter` and they all work fine, but hibernate is not generating the correct query when using `not in @Filter`.

Comment: I guess the trouble is hibernate cannot use NOT IN for forming joins. See if there a provision to use sub queries where you apply the filters to the sub query and then join outside.